# Android click on EditText won't show softkeyboard

Tags: android, onclick, focus, android-softkeyboard

It happens when the user dismisses the softkeyboard and then tries to click/gain focus on the EditText again, nothing happens only the cursor is shown - I want to show the keyboard again.

I've tried:

- Using an onclick event
- Using a focuschanged event
- Changing properties of the EditText (focusable etc...)

Note: I am currently using Paranoid Android. The EditText is Multiline.

Comment: can you please provide your activity/fragment + xml.

Comment: @FullPatrickJoin thanks, I tried to remove attributes one by one, and eventually I got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, I just had to **remove** the following attribute from my EditText:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please start by omitting any requestFocus defined for your EditText. 
there's a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2705)  that prevents keyboard from showning if the latter is set.

If that doesn't work for you, create a focus listener and in it programmatically open the virt keyboard:

```
editTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            // show keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(editTxt, 0);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
final InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
EditText e= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
e.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imm.showSoftInput(e, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
    e.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(e.getWindowToken(), 0);
                //Do you work here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and the edittext will be:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>
```